# Using Rsync with Makefile

Tags: makefile, rsync

I am trying to use a makefile to sync some of my directories that are on my pc with my thumb drive. For this purpose, I am using multiple commands in a single target.
The makefile looks somewhat like this

```
pend:
    rsync -avhzPu /foo/ /bar/  
    rsync -avhzPu /bob/ /alice/
```

But, every time I am doing `make -f .sync pend` only the first command runs and gives some output along with some error

```
sent 45.78K bytes  received 3.32K bytes  98.20K bytes/sec
total size is 4.42G  speedup is 89,981.37
rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1196) [sender=3.1.2]
.sync:14: recipe for target 'pend' failed
make: *** [pend] Error 23
```

But when I am running the commands separately it works. I am not sure what wrong I am doing here.

Comment: Why the `; \\` at the end of each line ?

Comment: for multiline commands. Shouldn't they be there?

Comment: You wouldn't normally do this in a makefile - you can have as many commands as you like under the dependency line, without any `;` separators or `\\` line continuation stuff. See: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Rule-Introduction

Comment: Thanks for the correction. I did the changes in the makefile. still, the error is not gone. I am not sure whether the error is a rsync thing or a makefile one @PaulR

Comment: It may be that `~` is not evaluated in a makefile context - try using `$(HOME)` instead.

Comment: Oh, that I used to show a typical dir. I am actually giving the absolute path to the directory in my Makefile. BTW I changed it to avoid confusion.

Comment: OK - in that case I'm out of ideas...

Comment: "_But when I am running the commands separately it works_*: when you run them separately on the command line interface or separately as two separate make rules?

Comment: I have tried both ways. I ran them as individual commands and as well as different make rules @RenaudPacalet

Comment: Then, the only explanations I can imagine are: 1) the rsync command you are using is not the same when it succeeds and when it fails or 2) the environment differs (invocation from different directories, environment variables...)

Comment: Just to be sure: if you type `rsync -avhzPu /foo/ /bar/` in the command line interface, you don't have any error and the transfer works as expected. Same if you leave only this single line in the `pend` recipe of your Makefile and you type `make -f .sync pend`: you don't have any error and the transfer works as expected. But as soon as you add the second line to the recipe, you get an error. Is that true?

Comment: Yes you are exactly right. In the make file I define some directory variables and use them at a later point in place of /foo/ /bar/. When I run them one after one in the make section pend then only I get stuck. It seems really strange to me.

Comment: I have got spaces in the directory name and that's why rsync is failing. I've found it at last.

Answer (score 3):

From the output...

```
sent 45.78K bytes  received 3.32K bytes  98.20K bytes/sec
total size is 4.42G  speedup is 89,981.37
rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1196) [sender=3.1.2]
.sync:14: recipe for target 'pend' failed
make: *** [pend] Error 23
```

...the first `rsync` is failing.  If it ends with a non-zero exit code then `make` will simply bail at that point.  If you want `make` to continue with further commands in the rule then you can explicitly request that it should ignore non-zero exit codes by prefixing a command with a `-`...

```
pend:
    -rsync -avhzPu /foo/ /bar/
    -rsync -avhzPu /bob/ /alice/
```

This assumes, of course, that simply continuing with the commands is the desired behaviour.  Otherwise you need to think more carefully about how to proceed.

Comment: ... But you should properly understand why it's failing and only then decide whether the failure is one you can ignore, or, better yet, one you can eliminate or work around so that `rsync` doesn't fail. There is a good reason `make` aborts when a command fails.

Comment: @tripleee Of course.  Edited the answer to add a proviso.

Comment: The rsync is probably failing because it copies across file systems of different type (UFS to FAT for example) and the destination file system has no equivalent notion of certain attributes like ownership and permissions.